# Does $\{e_n\}$ have a cluster point?

Tags: general-topology, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be an infinite dimensional Banach space and $\{e_n\}$ is a sequence of basis elements. Is it justified to say $\{e_n\}$ has no cluster point?

I think it is true (looking at euclidean spaces) but I cannot figure out why! Would somebody help me?

Comment: This is true for orthonormal bases of Hilbert spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not necessarily.

Take for example $X=\{\,f\in L^2[-\pi,\pi]: f(-x)=-f(x)\}$. Then 
$$
f_1=\sin x, \, f_n=\sin x+\frac{\sin nx}{n}, \,n>1,
$$
is a sequence a basis elements with cluster point $f_1$.

Comment: What if $||e_n||=1$ for all n?

Comment: @Jave in such case just multiply the $e_n$'s suitably so that $\|e_n\|=1$.

Comment: Thank you so much